# Normalize sum of values to percentages from 0-100

Tags: summation

I have two values that sum to one in an arbitrary manner:

[.6 , .4]
   [-.2, 1.2]
   [1.9, -.9]
etc...

How can I "normalize" these values so that they represent a percentage from 0-100%? What mathematical concepts should I be looking at to make this transform happen across all variations of the summation, and will it skew the relationship between my number?

Answer (score 1):

Having two real numbers that add up to $1$ means having $x$ and $1-x$, where $x$ can be any real number. Since $1-x$ carries no new information compared to $x$, we can forget it and focus on $x$. Then the problem becomes: how to map $\mathbb R$ into $(0,100)$ in a reasonable way? Possible answer: take some [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) and normalize it to have range $(0,100)$. For example, 
$$x\mapsto \frac{100}{1+e^{-x}}$$